# admin users will be invalid in asp.net membership after a while

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, authentication, asp.net-membership

Our website uses Membership provider and has an admin panel that a number of users have access to it. the problem is admin Users can't login after a while and when I debug login codes, "***Membership.ValidateUser(username, password)***" method condition results false. I can't find the reason and also check the difference between valid and invalid users and can't find any things.it should be noted when I comment the ValidateUser method, user can login. How can I solve this problem?

thanks.

Login code:

```
protected void btnSignIn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Membership.ValidateUser(txtEmail.Text, txtPassword.Text))
    {
        var member = Membership.GetUser(txtEmail.Text);
        if (member.IsLockedOut)
        {
            if (DateTime.Now.Subtract(member.LastLockoutDate).TotalMinutes > 10)
            {
                member.UnlockUser();
            }
            else
            {
                (Page as BasePage).Alert("Your account due to entering the wrong credentials more than 5 times, has been blocked, please right after 10 minutes to re-enter your user information.");
                return;
            }
        }

        if (Request.QueryString["ReturnUrl"] != null)
        {
            FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(txtEmail.Text, false);
        }
        else
        {
            if (Roles.IsUserInRole(txtEmail.Text, SiteUtility.SiteRoles.admin.ToString()) || Roles.IsUserInRole(txtEmail.Text, SiteUtility.SiteRoles.adminl2.ToString()))
            {
                FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(txtEmail.Text, false);
                Response.Redirect("/admin/");
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if (Page is BasePage)
        {
            (Page as BasePage).Alert("Username or password is incorrect.");
        }
        else
        {
            Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(typeof(Page), "alterror", "alert('Username or password is incorrect.');", true);
        }
    }
}
```

Membership provider config in web.config

```
<membership userIsOnlineTimeWindow="10" hashAlgorithmType="SHA1">
  <providers>
    <clear/>
    <add name="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider" passwordFormat="Hashed" connectionStringName="CSConnectionString" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" requiresUniqueEmail="false" maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="2" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" passwordAttemptWindow="10" applicationName="ApplicationKaspid"/>
  </providers>
</membership>
```

Comment: i googled "asp net Membership.ValidateUser" and got several similar issues. a couple responses: "you've not set the PasswordAttemptWindow to some exact time."; "You need to set the applicationName property when configuring ASP.NET 2.0 Membership and other Providers." hope that helps (doubtful i know). looks mysterious...

Comment: Thanks @wazz, I set the applucationName in web.config, but I don't know how to set PasswordAttemptWindow

Comment: it's the second result in that google search. here's the link (it's old tho, so fwiw): https://forums.asp.net/t/1634684.aspx?Can+t+Get+Membership+ValidateUser+to+Work

Comment: As you can see, I set passwordAttemptWindow="10" and other configs, but the problem is still there

Comment: Can you describe what you mean by "Users can't login after a while" ?  What is the timing like?

Comment: I do not know how long after it happens. when user try to log in, "Username or password is incorrect." Message displayed to the user as shown in my code.

Answer (score 1):

Membership.Validate returns false for locked users.
After 5 invalid password attempts members are locked and you need to unlock members before validate.

```
protected void btnSignIn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var member = Membership.GetUser(txtEmail.Text);
    if (member != null)
    {
        if (member.IsLockedOut)
        {
            if (DateTime.Now.Subtract(member.LastLockoutDate).TotalMinutes > 10)
            {
                member.UnlockUser();
            }
            else
            {
                (Page as BasePage).Alert("Your account due to entering the wrong credentials more than 5 times, has been blocked, please right after 10 minutes to re-enter your user information.");
                return;
            }
        }
    }

    if (Membership.ValidateUser(txtEmail.Text, txtPassword.Text))
    {
        if (Request.QueryString["ReturnUrl"] != null)
        {
            FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(txtEmail.Text, false);
        }
        else
        {
            if (Roles.IsUserInRole(txtEmail.Text, SiteUtility.SiteRoles.admin.ToString()) || Roles.IsUserInRole(txtEmail.Text, SiteUtility.SiteRoles.adminl2.ToString()))
            {
                FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(txtEmail.Text, false);
                Response.Redirect("/admin/");
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if (Page is BasePage)
        {
            (Page as BasePage).Alert("Username or password is incorrect.");
        }
        else
        {
            Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(typeof(Page), "alterror", "alert('Username or password is incorrect.');", true);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: "If (Member.IsLockedOut)" condition return false, it means that user is not locked.

Comment: Member.IsLockedOut return false when user is not locked, but your code not even reach there if user is already locked. Membership.ValidateUser fails for locked users

Comment: I Changed the code as you've written and nothing change unfortunately.